# A better way to use mod_rewrite & php in translating pages?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to translate these pages from English to French:

- /about.php
- /contact.php
- `/paintings.php?id={$id}&title={$title}`

I created the following link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"> <?php if($language !== 1): ?>English<?php else: ?>French<?php endif; ?></a>
```

With this code behind it:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];                                                     
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $pattern1 = '&lang=' . $_GET['lang'];
    $pattern2 = '?lang=' . $_GET['lang'];
    $patternTotal = array($pattern1, $pattern2);
    $url = str_replace($patternTotal, '', $url);
    $language = 1;
} 
else if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?')) {
    $url .= '&lang=en';
    $language = 0;
} 
else {
    $url .= '?lang=en';
    $language = 0;
}
```

What I want for it to do is to return `1` to `$language` if the `lang` parameter is set to any value. Then I will use an if statement to fetch and display the content accordingly.

However I realized that this url `/paintings.php?id={$id}&title={$title}` looks bad and I used `mod_rewrite` to get it to this version `/{$id}/{$title}` with this `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /photo.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]`. And things broke. While the `$url` works on all the other pages on the paintings one it doesn't.

I have a feeling that I got it all wrong. How can I make it work? Also, is there a more efficient way in doing this?

Comment: Your code for creating the link is very messy. Create a string for the href in PHP then echo it. Don't embed the logic in the output. Why are you using your own method for encoding language preference?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, please? The current `$url` changes its value based on the `$_GET['lang']` parameter.